# Passing checkbox values to javascript and PHP mail

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm trying to pass checkbox values to PHP but the interests field shows up blank. I removed the javascript validation and sent it straight to PHP. All the other fields are displaying fine. I want to list the checked box only.

```
HTML
====================================
<fieldset>
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Workout" /><label for="workout">Workout</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Practice" /><label for="practice">Practice</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="interests[]" value="Training" /><label for="practice">Training</label><br />
</fieldset>
```

```
PHP
====================================
<?php

$field_full_name = $_POST['names'];

if(isset($_POST['interests'])){
$field_interests = 'interests';
}


$mail_to = 'me@mail.com';

$subject = 'Message from a visitor '.$field_full_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_full_name."\n";

$body_message .= 'Interest: '.$field_interests."\n";

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);


if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        window.location = 'index.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: how are you submitting the form?  also, what do you get when you print_r($_POST);

Comment: try $body_message .= 'Interest: '.$field_interests."\n"; change to $body_message .= 'Interest: '.$field_interests[0]."\n";

Answer (score 0):

That's because it is an array, not a scalar value; or at least it was until you replaced it by a string. Replace this:

```
$field_interests = 'interests';
```

with

```
$field_interests = (is_array($_POST['interests']) ? $_POST['interests'] : []);
$field_interests = (count($field_interests) > 0 ? implode(',', $field_interests) : 'none');
```

You also really read up on safely turning raw strings into html though, you're bound to create truckloads of bugs along your way with these kinds of lines

```
$body_message = 'From: '.$field_full_name."\n";
```

Use `htmlentities` or `htmlspecialchars` to encode strings to html,

```
$body_message = 'From: ' . htmlentities($field_full_name) . "\n";
```

or better yet,

```
$body_message = sprintf('From: %s' . PHP_EOL, htmlentities($field_full_name) );
```

Comment: DCR and Raxi thank you both for your help. Unfortantly, I haven't been able to resolve this issue. There's a jquery element to this that I don't think to add because it was apart of the validation process.

Comment: ` $('#register-form').each( function(){
  var form = $(this);
  //form.validate();
  form.submit(function(e) {
   if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    jQuery.post(this.action,{
     'names':$('input[name="register_names"]').val(),
     'email':$('input[name="register_email"]').val(),
    },function(data){
     form.fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).siblings('p.register_success_box').show();
     });
    });
    e.preventDefault();
   }
  });
 })`